# Storing multiple arrays in a np.zeros or np.ones

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to initialize a dummy array of length `n` using `np.zeros(n)` with `dtype=object`. I want to use this dummy array to store `n` copies of another array of length `m`.
I'm trying to avoid for loop to set values at each index.

I tried using the below code but keep getting error -

```
temp = np.zeros(10, dtype=object)
arr = np.array([1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5])
res = temp * arr
```

The desired result should be -

```
np.array([[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5], [1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5], ... 10 copies])
```

I keep getting the error -

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (5,)
```

I understand that this error arises since the compiler thinks I'm trying to multiply those arrays.
So how do I achieve the task?

Comment: consider using numpy.tile function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Answer (score 0):

[`np.tile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) is a built-in function that repeats a given array `reps` times. It looks like this is exactly what you need, i.e.:

```py
res = np.tile(arr, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr = np.array([1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5])
>>> arr
array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5])
>>> np.array([arr]*10)

array([[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]])
```